# Grouping a series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I do not know much about it so please take it easy on me.
I was trying to plot Area vs. freuency of Fire in areas A and B from 2009 to 2013 in a line graph. I figured out how to import a .csv file but I am having problem grouping the series and creating graph.
My csv file looks like this:

```
Date, Area, NaturalDisaster
12/10/2009, A, Fire
12/13/2009, B, Flood
01/12/2010, B, Fire
05/01/2011, A, Fire
30/11/2012, B, Flood
14/03/2013, B, Fire
```

So can you please help me to get started with this. I will appreciate any help of any kind.
Thank you.

Comment: Ffisegydd: I have not written much. I really could not get a start on this. All I have done is imported  pandas, numphy, and matplotlib. :)

Comment: I would like to have areas A and B on X axis and frequency of fire on each area on Y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group data in pandas.

The main idea behind `groupby` and similar functions is ["Split - Apply - Combine"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) whereby, in general, you:

- Split your dataset into groups,
- Apply some aggregate function to each of the individual groups,
- Re-combine them together in a new dataframe.

To get the frequency of fires that occur within areas A and B you must first select only rows that are fires, and not floods, you can do this using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with:

```
df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire']
```

You then need to groupby (or split) based on the Area (A or B). You can do this simply using `groupby('Area')`. Adding this to the previous line of code this becomes:

```
df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire'].groupby('Area')
```

Finally in pandas you need to [apply some aggregate function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) to your groups (the apply stage), we're going to use `count()` to count the amount of results. This line then becomes:

```
df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire'].groupby('Area').count()
```

There's a problem though. This result has two columns with the exact same numbers in them. That's because we counted both the `Date` column and the `NaturalDisaster` column. This duplicate information can be annoying to deal with, so let's just take one column when doing the count. The final line then becomes

```
areas = df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire'].groupby('Area')['NaturalDisaster'].count()
```

We now have the count of fire incidents that occurred in areas A and B, but ideally we want the frequency. We can get this by dividing by the total number of fire incidents which is given by `sum(areas)`:

```
areas /= sum(areas)
```

We now have a dataframe with the frequency of fire incidents in the areas A and B. We can [plot this as a bar chart](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html) simply using

```
areas.plot(kind='bar')
```

Bringing all the code together into one bunch, it becomes:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


s = '''Date, Area, NaturalDisaster
12/10/2009, A, Fire
12/13/2009, B, Flood
01/12/2010, B, Fire
05/01/2011, A, Fire
30/11/2012, B, Flood
14/03/2013, B, Fire'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',\s+', engine='python')

# Ignore everything above this part, it's simply creating your dataframe.

areas = df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire'].groupby('Area')['NaturalDisaster'].count() 
areas /= sum(areas)

areas.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Finally, I answered the question using groupby because you specifically asked about it, but you could also use [`pandas.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) to do this same operation (and similarly powerful things). Creating the `areas` dataframe using `pivot_table` would be something like

```
areas = pd.pivot_table(df[df['NaturalDisaster']=='Fire'],
                       values='NaturalDisaster', 
                       index='Area', 
                       aggfunc='count')
```

You'd then continue with the same code as given above.

Comment: Ffisegydd: Thank you so much. Now I completely understand it.You wrote a nice tutorial for me. Really appreciate your kind help!!! :) :)